# Async call passing props and displaying list

Tags: react-native

I have a component, Messages, which makes an async call to get some data. I have a MessageList component which handles the list stuff.

Messages passes a dataSource prop to MessageList. MessageList displays all items in dataSource using

```
{this.props.dataSource.map((result, index) =>
     (<MessageListItem key = {index} rowData = {result}></MessageListItem>)
 )}
```

Problem: All MessageListItems contain the same data. All 18 items display as the first item in the array.

In my getInitialState for MessageListItems, I print out the prop values in the log, and it prints out the correct data for each prop that gets passed. So why is getInitialValues seeing the correct data but when it actually renders the component, it all shows up as the same component?

Answer (score 0):

As habit from angular, I was assigning

var self = this

in my getInitialState.

Apparently this was causing some sort of scoping issue. When I removed all references to self and just used this, the problem went away. I haven't had issues before, but in this particular instance, it wasn't correct. So I guess lesson here is to always use this?